# Can I create a venv with already locally installed packages?

Tags: python, python-venv

I already have some locally installed Python packages in `~/.local`. Some of them are self-built packages. And now I want to create a new virtual environment, is there any way to create a virtual environment with those locally installed packages?

`pip -r requirement.txt` doesn't work for me since some of the packages are self-built. The building time is very long hence I'd like to know if it's possible to create a virtual environment with those libraries.

Comment: Typically you can enable "system site packages". Maybe this is what you need. -- Which tool exactly do you use to create your virtual environments? -- You added a bunch of tags that seem to relate to some specific tools, but since your actual question does not mention any of them, it makes me think you added random tags somewhat loosely related to virtual environments, so I removed them.

Comment: Can't you just copy that venv folder?

Comment: In the new virtual environment you could try adding a `.pth` file pointing to your other "site packages" directory. There is some [documentation about `.pth` files in `site`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html?highlight=pth), and you should be able to look up more resources about this on other places.

Comment: can try to install the package with pip install ~./local/package_name, as long as it got setup or pyproject it will build and install